# simple WSDL and JAX RPC mapping file generating tools

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rpc

guys, what are the simple tools for generating WSDL and JAX RPC mapping files from java ServiceEndPoint Interface. or I just need that generates JAX RPC mapping file generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I got it is wscompile tool. Thanks to sun Java Web Services Developer kit